# PHP does not show some kind of errors (from apache)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working on server with

```
ubuntu 14.04 
php 5.3.10.
apache 2.2.22
```

these are php.ini error settings:

```
display_errors = off
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

the apache version of php.ini differs from cli version about some functions disabled:

```
pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
```

here's my code:

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
ini_set('error_log','/tmp/php_errors_'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'.log');
abstract class master 
{
    abstract public function metodo ();
}

class slave extends master
{
    function __contruct()
    {
        echo "HI!";
    }
}

$b = new slave();
```

from CLI I'll get this error ():

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class slave contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (master::metodo) in /home/lbarby/prova.php on line 13
```

but running the same script from apache I obtain blank page!
What's the matter?
Any advice?

**UPDATE**
To be clear: my problem is that I don't understand why PHP under apache doesn't show any error while it does from CLI (as expected!).

---

**SOLVED**
I've found a solution: instead of use literal value you must use numeric ones (see predefined constant on php.net).

Comment: try changing the constructor from `function __contruct()` to `public function __contruct()`

Comment: why not just implement the required abstract method `metodo`in the slave class?

Comment: thank you but my problem is that running on apache I'll get blank screen so forget about code, it's just for testing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn **[display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)** to on. If it is set to off it will show nothing.

Comment: have you seen this row?
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Comment: Of course. Directly from PHP's manual: "Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any effect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed."

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem.
I've turned on display_errors and display_startup_errors too but nothing change.

Comment: Just to check, but did you change it in the php.ini associated to the apache server, right ?

Comment: Yep! To be sure I've checked using phpinfo.